# Mouse not showing and uncontrollable

Tags: windows, mouse

One week ago I had a problem when I started my PC. The mouse (HyperX pulsefire surge) was invisible. The RGB works, left click, right click, DPI button works too. But the cursor were invisible and impossible to move it.

My keyboard works, same for my mic and the headset (all are from HyperX).

I tried everything I read and nothing worked. But, like I said, one week ago I got the same problem but I deleted the %temp%'s files and after the restart the mouse was back. But right now it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the mouse drivers and/or software?

Comment: Also have you tried a simpler and different mouse?

Comment: Yes I tried a simpler and différent mouse and same problem, clicks works but cursor IS invisible and dont move ! I tried to uninstall and reinstall drivers too by the panel

Comment: Do a Repair Install of your operating system.   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11  ....  Since the mouse is a base hardware item, you may have to back up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: Do I will lose all my datas, and need to "re-setup" everythings ? (GPU drivers, settings for Windows etc) btw thanks, I'm gonna try that tonight and I will be back

Comment: Repair Install Keep Everything does not lose any data.  Some (even most) drivers will be updated.

Comment: Hey, so. I lost some datas but nothing important (some softwares but idc) and... the mouse is rgb, right click left click works etc but she's invisible and can't move. BUT ! Now I'm using a new mouse and now it's working (before it won't) so... I don't know, maybe the mouse was the problem and she can't move but I think it's really strange, why she's invisible (she's not when I'm using a new mouse, unplug the new and plus the old one, she's not invisible but don't move)

Maybe it's just the mouse, I'm lil bit lost. But now the simpler mouse works, strange...

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix that at least worked for me.

1. Using your keyboard navigate to Task Manager and disable NGENUITY from starting on your computer.
2. Restart your computer
3. Hold down the DPI button and the MOUSE WHEEL button at the same time for at least 10 seconds, You should see your mouse rgb restart and your cursor unfreezes. This basically factory resets your mouse.

I hope this helped :)

Comment: A reference would help others have more trust in your answer.